# Styles not being applied for the webvtt file contents

Tags: html, css, mozilla, webvtt

I am new to using the webvtt files. I have been trying to apply styles for the contents of the webvtt file. I am using the example thats given in the MDN website. This is what my code looks like.

```
WEBVTT

STYLE

::cue {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, dimgray, lightgray);
  color: papayawhip;
}

/* Style blocks cannot use blank lines nor "dash dash greater than" */

NOTE comment blocks can be used between style blocks.

STYLE

::cue(b) {
  color: peachpuff;
}

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000

- Hello <b>world</b>.
```

I still dont see the styles being applied to the text. Is there any reason for this? Did I miss something? TIA.